# Segmentation Fault in C. Works in main but not my function

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that will check a name the user enters to a file and see how many occurences there are of it within the file. However in my getrawdata func I keep getting a segmentation fault.

Here is the code:

```
struct NameRecord{ // Holds all the name information
    int year;
    char name [31];
    int frequency;
};


void allCaps(char s[]){ //Capitalizes all of the characters of s
    int i=0;
    while (s[i])
        {
            s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
            i++;
        }
    printf("The name entered is now in all caps! %s", s);
}

int getRawData1(FILE* male, struct NameRecord records[], int currSize){
    int readResult;
    printf("The current size is %d", currSize);
    readResult=fscanf(&*male, "%d", &records[currSize].year);
}
//Main
int main (){
    char name [31];
    FILE *male;
    FILE *female;
    int size = 0;
    //Opening files
    male = fopen("malebabynames.csv", "r"); //Dont leave in home directory 
    female = fopen("femalebabynames.csv", "r");
    struct NameRecord records[160000];

    if ( male==NULL){
        printf ("Error: the data file does not exist");
    }
    if ( female==NULL){
        printf ("Error: the data file does not exist");
    }

    size = getRawData1(male, records, size);
    //Output   
    printf("Please enter a name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    allCaps(name);
}
```

#### Revised code — still crashing

Original version at [Codepad](http://codepad.org/cgpfYQkm); this version [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)'d.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct NameRecord
{
    int year;
    char name[31];
    int frequency;
};
struct NameRecord records[160000];

void allCaps(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i])
    {
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("The name entered is now in all caps! %s", s);
}

int getRawData1(FILE *male, struct NameRecord records[], int currSize)
{
    int readResult;
    printf("The current size is %d", currSize);
    readResult = fscanf(male, "%d,%[^,],%d\n", &records[currSize].year,
                        records[currSize].name, records[currSize].frequency);

    while (readResult == 3)
    {
        currSize++;
        readResult = fscanf(male, "%d,%[^,],%d\n", &records[currSize].year,
                            records[currSize].name, &records[currSize].frequency);
    }
    printf("The size of the array is %d", currSize);
    return currSize;
}

int main()
{
    char name[31];
    FILE *male;
    FILE *female;
    int size = 0;

    male = fopen("malebabynames.csv", "r");
    female = fopen("femalebabynames.csv", "r");
    int i = 0;
    int readResult;
    if (male == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: the data file does not exist");
    }
    if (female == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: the data file does not exist");
    }
    getRawData1(male, records, size);

    printf("Welcome to the Name Popularity Checker \n====================================== \n");
    printf("Please enter a name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    allCaps(name);
}
```

Comment: There's no `return` statement in `getRawData1`

Comment: Make sure you turn on compiler warnings and *pay attention to them* - `gcc -Wall ...` or equivalent would have saved you a lot of grief here.

Comment: Sorry about that. There actually was one but I didn't copy it over by mistake. It still a segmentation fault however.

Comment: And check the return value from `fscanf()` and any other input function to make sure that it did read what you expected it to read.

Comment: This looks wrong `&*male`

Comment: SO how would I make it update the copy of records in main?

Comment: My mistake I thought it was a struct

Comment: @Hogan: it is certainly aconventional to use the `&*male` notation; it is not actually incorrect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - That is why I said it looks wrong, not that it was wrong.  :)

Comment: @Hogan: you need to explain why it looks wrong, then. It doesn't help someone struggling if you point out an esoteric issue that is tangential to the real problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Aren't the files checked right after they're opened in `main`? Looks like it to me...

Comment: [link] (http://codepad.org/cgpfYQkm) this is my most recently updated code. Still getting the fault even with everyones suggestions

Comment: @user3075178 Just to check, could you try your program with only, say, 100 NameRecords? I realize there may be more in the file, but just to see if this is the cause of your segmentation fault.

Comment: @aardvarkk yes I have tried it as well and still it occurs :(. Really stumped here.

Comment: @aardvarkk: There's a check and we can assume that in fact the error messages are not firing, but if the open fails, the null `FILE` pointers will still be used because the flow of control is not broken in the `if` statements that test them.  I was partially wrong in my previous comment (now removed), but also partially correct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point -- it just prints a message and keeps going.

Comment: @user3075178 Updated my answer to help you make sure you're loading the files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This actually crashes in VS2012 for me on startup because of this line:

`struct NameRecord records[160000];`

I think you may be exceeding your available stack space. At least it was for me! Does that number need to be so high? Can you dynamically allocate based on what you read in from the file?

Taking Barmar's suggestion below, you can do this to fix it (if you really need a static allocation of 160k records):

```
struct NameRecord{ // Holds all the name information
  int year;
  char name [31];
  int frequency;
};

NameRecord records[160000];
```

In other words, make it a global variable instead of a variable on the stack.

**UPDATE:** Also, using Jonathan Leffler's advice, you could make sure you're opening the files correctly. You're currently just printing a message if the files don't open correctly, but you should not continue execution if that's the case.

```
if (male == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: the data file does not exist");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if (female == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: the data file does not exist");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Or make it a static variable instead of local to main

Comment: Yeah. It actually has to do to how big the file is.

Comment: Or reduce the size to 160; most school exercises won't have 160,000 entries.

Comment: If you really need that many, then I'll update to reflect Barmar's suggestion.

Comment: Maybe a pointer could be used, a pointer on the stack would not cause an overflow (they're not so big.)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to compiler warnings. If you aren't getting compiler warnings, turn them on; if you still aren't getting compiler warnings, get a better compiler.

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition x.c -o x
x.c: In function ‘getRawData1’:
x.c:30:25: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
                         records[currSize].name, records[currSize].frequency);
                         ^
x.c:30:25: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
$
```

You are missing an `&`.

```
                         records[currSize].name, &records[currSize].frequency);
```

(I'd already added `#include <ctype.h>` and put `static` in front of the functions to quell other warnings from the compiler.)

---

You should also redesign the interface to `getRawData1()`:

```
int getRawData1(FILE *fp, struct NameRecord records[], int maxSize)
{
    int readResult;
    printf("The maximum size is %d", maxSize);
    int currSize = 0;

    while (currSize < maxSize &&
           (readResult = fscanf(fp, "%d,%[^,],%d\n", &records[currSize].year,
                                records[currSize].name, &records[currSize].frequency)) == 3)
        currSize++;

    printf("The amount of data in the array is %d", currSize);
    return currSize;
}
```

Called:

```
num_male_names = getRawData1(male, records, 160000);
```

This prevents buffer overflow if there are more than 160,000 records in the file.

Comment: I WISH I HAD REP TO UPVOTE YOU!!! Thank you so much Jonathan, this has really helped me out. My fault is now fixed and I continue to work on the assignment :D. Thanks once again.